# TCHAR [ ] convert to String

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to convert the `TCHAR nameBuf[]` into `string`.

```
TCHAR nameBuf[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 2];

DWORD nameBufSize;

nameBufSize = sizeof nameBuf - 1;

GetComputerName(nameBuf, &nameBufSize); //store computer name into nameBuf

_tprintf(_T("%s"), nameBuf); //print the computer name
```

Comment: You *could* use a `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`, but why not just use wide characters in the first place?

Comment: Does the T here always mean wide?

Comment: _T would be wide only when _UNICODE_ is defined.

Comment: Can you provide me the modified code?

Comment: Why are you using `TCHAR`? Are you really still supporting Windows 98?

Comment: I found this code in internet and I'm facing a problem to convert it to string.

Comment: @XynusChan, so why not change the code to use wide chars instead? TCHAR is pointless nowadays (not that it ever had much point in the first place).

Comment: @XynusChan *I found this code in internet.* Therein lies your problem.  Instead of copying blindly you should seek to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make the type clear. See modified code below:

```
WCHAR nameBuf[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 2];

DWORD nameBufSize;

nameBufSize = sizeof nameBuf - 1;

GetComputerNameW(nameBuf, &nameBufSize); //store computer name into nameBuf

wprintf_s(L"%s", nameBuf); //print the computer name
```

Comment: Then how to make `string NAME = nameBuf` ?

Comment: `nameBufSize = sizeof nameBuf - 1`; should be `nameBufSize = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1`. because the size should be in characters not bytes.

Comment: @Xynus if you need to use string and not wstring, then use the "A" equivalents instead of "W".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use narrow chars (seems like you do) then this code

```
char nameBuf[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 2];
DWORD nameBufSize;
nameBufSize = sizeof nameBuf - 1;
GetComputerNameA(nameBuf, &nameBufSize); //store computer name into nameBuf
printf_s("%s", nameBuf); //print the computer name
string NAME = nameBuf;
```

Untested code